# Unintended multiple evaluation of parameter in macro

Tags: c, macros

Why the the output of the second printf is: max of 50 and 67 is 62 ? Why not  max of 50 and 62 is 57?

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((a)>(b) ? (a): (b))
int incr(){
    static int i =42;
    i += 5;
    return i;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    int x = 50;
    printf("max of %d and %d is %d\n",x, incr(), MAX(x, incr()));
    printf("max of %d and %d is %d",x, incr(), MAX(x, incr()));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just write a `static` function. Your compiler will probably inline it for you anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf("max of %d and %d is %d\n",x, incr(), MAX(x, incr()));
```

After the macro substitution, it becomes:

```
printf("max of %d and %d is %d\n",x, incr(), ((x)>(incr()) ? (x): (incr())));
//                                    ^1            ^2               ^3
```

`incr()` is called multiple times in this single function call, it's unspecified which argument is evaluated first. Whether the first or the second is called first make the result unexpected.

The only thing to be certain is due to the short circuit of `?:`, `(x)>(incr()` is evaluated to determine if the expression has the value of `(x)` or the value of the third the `incr()`.

Comment: To be nitpicky, no value is passed to `MAX`. The string `incr()` is passed to `MAX`. It transforms it into `((x)>(incr()) ? (x): (incr()))`. There are two or three evaluations of `incr()` in those lines, depending on which fork `?:` takes. But yeah, undefined behaviour and all that. @erapert: No, the function call is not necessarily evaluated left-to-right; this kind of thing should be avoided.

Comment: @Amadan there is no undefined behaviour here; only unspecified

Comment: @MattMcNabb: You are right, unspecified. YuHao, yes :)